# Convert pptx into html view using docx4j

Tags: android, powerpoint, file-conversion, docx4j

Can anyone help me in converting a pptx into html view using docx4j.jar. Though I have gone through a lot of related questions already asked in this forum but none helped me. Please give me a brief conversion process(just name the related classes and their methods to invoke).
Well, m doing all this in my "Android" app and dont want any third party software(need to open pptx within my app only).

Comment: this should help http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.docx4java.org%2Fblog%2F2012%2F05%2Fjaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android%2F&ei=GL87UMr7OpGo8AS1zIDADw&usg=AFQjCNHZMaEFrQVxnI4qwptREPVU-k6NRw&sig2=feSlMMLy0hGbDKURPCqGcg

Answer (score 1):

First, see [jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/)

Next, try [RenderAsSvgInHtml.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/pptx4j/java/org/pptx4j/samples/RenderAsSvgInHtml.java)

Or, try the pptx to xhtml conversion in Java first, to confirm it is enough for your needs (before you go to the Android-related effort).  At present, it is basically just text, lines and images, not custom shapes.

**Disclosure: I wrote the stuff referenced above.**